# how to get data from both table with join

Tags: php, mysql, join

Table 1 : **Main_Family_Member**

```
ID | Name
1  | Mahesh
2  | Rahul
3  | Jay
```

Table 2 : **Family_Members**

```
ID | MainMember | Name
1  | 1          | 'Arun'
2  | 1          | 'Nitin'
3  | 2          | 'Pratik'
```

**Want Result** :

```
Name
Mahesh
Arun
Nitin
Rahul
Pratik
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing a `UNION ALL` of the two tables along with proper ordering.  Note that it is necessary to union the two tables joined, because we need to know whether a main family member has any members.  In case he does not have any member, your sample output implies that you don't want to display that main family member at all.

```
SELECT t.Name
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.Name, 0 AS position
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name
        FROM Main_Family_Member t1
        INNER JOIN Family_Members t2
            ON t1.ID = t2.MainMember
        WHERE t2.ID IS NOT NULL
    ) t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.ID, t2.Name, 1 AS position
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t2.MainMember AS ID, t2.Name
        FROM Main_Family_Member t1
        INNER JOIN Family_Members t2
            ON t1.ID = t2.MainMember
        WHERE t2.ID IS NOT NULL
    ) t2
    ORDER BY ID, position, Name
) t
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Main_Family_Member.Name, Family_Members.Name
FROM Main_Family_Member
INNER JOIN Family_Members
ON Main_Family_Member.ID = Main_Family_Member.MainMember;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Main_Family_Member.Name, Family_Members.Name
FROM Main_Family_Member
INNER JOIN Family_Members
ON Main_Family_Member.ID = Main_Family_Member.MainMember;

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a `INNER JOIN` on the two tables. This would return all the rows in the first table that meet the conditions plus all rows on the second table that join with the first table on the unique fields.

`SELECT  Main_Family_Member.Name , Family_Members.Name FROM Main_Family_Member INNER JOIN Family_Members ON Main_Family_Member.ID = Family_Members.MainMember  WHERE Main_Family_Member.ID = 1 OR Main_Family_Member.ID = 2`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Main_Family_Member.Name,Family_Members.Name FROM Main_Family_Member 
INNER JOIN Family_Members ON Main_Family_Member.ID=Family_Members.MainMember
```

Comment: This will not work, You just make 2 column, the expected is 1 column and collecting all Name data